# Java second Frame not showing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, actionevent

I made a project where in a table you see 4 buttons and when you click on it another box has to appear, but me when I do it, the second window opens and both windows are closing I cannot access to the codes that are supposed to come out from the ActionPerformed() where it just pops up the other window and closing in less than 3 seconds without opening it, the other codes are working fine I tired, here's the code for the first box:

```
public class MathoQuest extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
    JButton boutConvert, boutGeo, boutFonc, boutOut;



    public MathoQuest() {
        setTitle("Bienvenue a MathoQuest");
        setSize(250,500);
        JPanel simplePanel = new JPanel();
        simplePanel.setLayout(null);
        add(simplePanel);
        Font helvb14 = new Font("Arial" , Font.BOLD , 30);


        boutConvert = new JButton("Convertir");
        boutConvert.setFont(helvb14);
        boutConvert.setForeground(Color.white);
        boutConvert.setBackground(new Color(63,107,220));
        simplePanel.add(boutConvert);
        boutConvert.setBounds(25,50,200,80);
        boutConvert.addActionListener(this);

        boutGeo = new JButton("Geometrie-\nEN CONSTRUCTION-");
        boutGeo.setFont(helvb14);
        boutConvert.setForeground(Color.white);
        boutGeo.setBackground(new Color(145,110,220));
        simplePanel.add(boutGeo);
        boutGeo.setBounds(25,150,200,80);
        boutGeo.addActionListener(this);

        boutFonc = new JButton("Fonction");
        boutFonc.setFont(helvb14);
        boutFonc.setForeground(Color.white);
        boutFonc.setBackground(new Color(150,200,80));
        simplePanel.add(boutFonc);
        boutFonc.setBounds(25,250,200,80);
        boutFonc.addActionListener(this);

        boutOut = new JButton("Quitter");
        boutOut.setFont(helvb14);
        boutOut.setForeground(Color.white);
        boutOut.setBackground(new Color(245,130,0));
        simplePanel.add(boutOut);
        boutOut.setBounds(25,350,200,80);
        boutOut.addActionListener(this);        


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MathoQuest mathframe = new MathoQuest();
    mathframe.setVisible(true);
        mathframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }    

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == boutConvert) {
                    ConversionFrame frame = new ConversionFrame();
                    frame.getContentPane();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == boutGeo) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ce mode est encore en construction merci de reessayer plus tard");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == boutFonc) {
                FonctionFrame dess = new FonctionFrame();
                dess.getContentPane();
        dess.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == boutOut)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Au revoir et merci d'avoir utilise cette application");
            System.exit(0);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried enclosing the last `if` condition in braces?

Without enclosing them, `System.exit(0);` will be called under any circumstance, and only the immediate line after the `if` will be part of it.

So the exit method will be part of the direct method, not of the `if` block.

Effectively, the program will look like this:

```
if (e.getSource() == boutOut)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Au revoir et merci d'avoir utilise cette application");
}

System.exit(0);
```

Whereas it should look like this:

```
if (e.getSource() == boutOut)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Au revoir et merci d'avoir utilise cette application");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Anytime man. Also, advice from a rookie like myself: Auto indent the program before compilation - it really helps in debugging error like this.

Comment: @studentofjava Most Java coding standards require the body of *every* if, while, and for statement to be enclosed in braces, even when it’s only one line long, for exactly this reason.  It’s a good habit to get into.

Comment: any idea how to keep my first window open after closing the new one? because when I press on X, the whole program is closing down

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder if you have an idea I would like to learn It